# Confusion in ternary operator and typecasting

Tags: c, type-conversion, ternary-operator, void-pointers

I gone through this question -

why the result of : `1 ? (int *)0 : (void *)0`

differs to the result of :
`1 ? (int *)0 : (void *)1`

How it is differ ? It should be `0` or `(int*)0`.
How to check the result ?

Where we can use such type of expression ?

Comment: @K-ballo: Why? It is not giving any compilation error.

Comment: @ouah: `void*` and `void*` differ? That's the type of both `a` and `b` ;)

Comment: So, where are you finding this a problem, @Vikram?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's not true, take a look at the answers.

Comment: @ouah: I don't need to. The declarations are `void *a, *b;`. No further information is necessary.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the right operands in `a` and `b` assignments have different types. When I said the *types differ* I was referring to the two conditional expressions of the original question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The only difference is in types: the first one returns an `int *`, the second one returns a `void *`.

From C11 standard, §6.5.15 *Conditional operator*, ¶6:

> If both the second and third operands are pointers or one is a null pointer constant and the other is a pointer, the result type is a pointer to a type qualified with all the type qualifiers of the types referenced by both operands. **Furthermore, if both operands are pointers to compatible types or to differently qualified versions of compatible types, the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type; if one operand is a null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand**; otherwise, one operand is a pointer to **`void`** or a qualified version of **`void`**, in which case the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of **`void`**.

(emphasis mine)

Remember that a pointer to non-`void` cannot be a *null pointer constant* but just a *null pointer*. C11 §6.3.2.3 *Pointers*, ¶3:

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type **`void *`**, is called a *null pointer constant*.<sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> <sup>66) The macro **`NULL`** is defined in **`<stddef.h>`** (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19.</sup>

So, here:

```
1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 0
```

`(int *) 0` is just a *null pointer* while `(void *) 0` is a *null pointer constant*, so the result has type `int *` ("*if one operand is a null pointer constant, the result has the type of the other operand*").

while here:

```
1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 1
```

there are no *null pointer constants* (only a *null pointer*, the first one), so the result has the composite type `void *` ("*if both operands are pointers to compatible types or to differently qualified versions of compatible types, the result type is a pointer to an appropriately qualified version of the composite type*").

The results have different types but they are both *null pointers*. Also note that the result is *never* `0` as you say in your question, it's always a pointer.

Unfortunately there is no standard way to see the difference in C, C++ has some support about it (`typeinfo`) but results are different there.

> Where we can use such type of expression?

I can't think about a useful and concrete use of this obscure corner of the language.

Comment: This answer is certainly wrong. `1` is regarded as true, so both operations evaluate to `((int *)0)`.

Comment: The second expression does not have any null pointer constant, so it returns the composite type `void *`, while the first one has a null pointer constant so it returns "_the other type_" `int *`, I don't understand, can you clarify please? `0` converted to `int *` is not a null pointer constant. Anyway, I will add something to make my answer clearer, right or wrong.

Comment: @H2CO3 strange, but `1 ? (int *)0 : (void *)1` actually yields the value `(void *) 0`

Comment: @ouah Not that strange, regarding that `?:` requires some consistency between the types of its last two operands.

Comment: Here I found a good explanation - http://carolina.mff.cuni.cz/~trmac/blog/2005/the-ugliest-c-feature-tgmathh/

Comment: @pmg the result type is different, but yes, the value it's the same.

Comment: My previous comment (about the value being the same) deleted. I understand the types are different ... and all values have a type :)

Comment: Just read the standard. This kind of casting is really sick. Anyway, the answer is correct. +1

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting this answer. This page presents a usecase of this feature, mainly for `_Generic` macros: https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/testing-compile-time-constness-and-null-pointers-with-c11s-_generic/ and his library (p99) contains several macros for evaluation depending on constness, volatileness, and so (see file p99_generic.h)

Comment: @LoPiTaL Hah, nice find! I hope the text I cited didn't change in C18... can't be bothered to check though.

Answer (score 4):

So [effeffe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14094142/1119701) already answered on why the two expressions differ:

```
1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 0  // yield (int *) 0
1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 1  // yield (void *) 0
```

To answer this question now:

> How to check the result ?

With `gcc` you can use `typeof` extension and `__builtin_types_compatible_p` builtin function:

```
// The two expressions differ
printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof(1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 0), typeof(1 ? (int *) 0 : (void *) 1)));

// First expression yield (int *) 0
printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof((int *) 0), typeof( 0 ? (int *)0 : (void *)0  )));

// Second expression yield (void *) 0
printf("%d\n", __builtin_types_compatible_p(typeof((void *) 0), typeof( 1 ? (int *)0 : (void *)1  )));
```