# Space-complexity for "count the number of occurrences in a sorted array" using binary searcg

Tags: arrays, sorting, time-complexity, binary-search, space-complexity

We know that we can count number of occurrences in a sorted array in O(LogN) time using binary search [1,2].

[1] http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-number-of-occurrences-in-a-sorted-array/

[2] [Count the number of occurrences of a number in a sorted array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094914/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-number-in-a-sorted-array)

What is the space-complexity of this solution?

Comment: Binary search in an already sorted contiguous array of elements has `O(1)` (or `O(0)`?) additional space requirements - you just need a pair of indexes/pointers to contain your current search range, and probably a pair of additional indexes/pointers to contain your search results... But perhaps you're thinking about space requirements for the sorting or something else? If so, you could be a little more verbose in precisely explaining your question...

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to have additional space. Only a few variables are enough. (with assumption that array is already sorted)