# Initializing a C struct array, with a size not known at compile time

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, memset

I didn't find an exact answer to this question so either it's a stupid question or just plain obvious.  I would like to know if it would produce undefined behaviour.

I have some struct type defined:

```
typedef struct {
    char string1[17];
    char string2[33];
    int   someInt;
    float someFloat;
} my_struct_t;
```

I need multiple instances of that struct (like you'd have in struct array), but the number of objects is unknown at compile time.

Is it correct to initialize it like this?

```
my_struct_t *myStruct;
size_t noOfElements;
size_t completeSize;
int index;    

/* ...code which sets the number of elements at runtime... */

completeSize = sizeof(my_struct_t) * noOfElements;

myStruct = malloc(completeSize);
memset(myStruct, 0, completeSize);

/* ...and then access it as if it were an array...*/

myStruct[index].someInt = 10; // index < noOfElements
```

Is it safe to do this? The `memset()` part is what I'm worried about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it safe to do this? The memset() part is what I'm worried about.

Yes, it's safe, in the sense that this won't cause any undefined behaviour (buffer overflows, uninitialised values, etc.).

However, it won't necessarily set your values to zero.  `memset` sets the **bits** to 0, but this isn't necessarily the same as setting e.g. a `float` to a value of `0` (although in practice, it will be fine on most normal platforms).

Comment: Thank you. So the entire memory which was allocated to the pointer will be zeroed out and there will be no overflows. That's good enough, but also thanks for the warning about integral type values.

Answer (score 10):

Using `malloc` followed by `memset` is OK so far as it goes, but you might wish to consider the (under-used) `calloc` instead.  For example:

```
pMyStruct = calloc(noOfElements, sizeof(my_struct_t));
```

This will allocate memory for the required number of elements, *and* initialise them to binary zero.

Comment: I would, but the platform I'm working with supports only a subset of standard C lib. calloc() unfortunately isn't available.

Comment: @Tomislav: strange, it should be in stdlib.h.  Anyway, looks like you are stuck with malloc and memset then.

Comment: It is strange. What's more strange than that is that I'm not even allowed to include any ANSI C headers. In fact, I can't even call malloc(). Instead I call a function with different name for which documentation states that it acts as a standard C malloc(). Go figure. Hence portability of the code I'm writing is not exactly my number one priority. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is it safe to do this? The memset() part is what I'm worried about.

You're right to be worried - your `memset` simply sets all bits to zero which doesn't necessarily set members to 0.

For instance, nothing guarantees all-bits-0 will actually mean 0 for a float. The same holds for a pointer: **making it all-bits-0 does not mean it will necessarily be `NULL`**.

---

#### EDIT

`NULL` may or may not be represented as all-bits-0. Quoting the C FAQ:

> The internal (or run-time) representation of a null pointer, which may
> or may not be all-bits-0 and which may be different for different
> pointer types.

Comment: Nothing guarantees it but the C Committee also says this: *"As far as the committee knows, all machines treat all bits zero as a representation of floating-point zero."*

Comment: @ouah Good to know :-) Better err on the safe side though

Comment: Pointers with all `0` bits are always _null pointers_ and they compare equal to the `NULL` macro, though they could not have the same type of `NULL`. Actually, `0` is a _null pointer constant_.

Comment: @effeffe Don't think so. Can you provide a quote ? http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: "_For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type."_ and I wrote something about _null pointers_ and _null pointers constants_ in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14094142/1202636). I don't think casts between different pointer types could change the value. Maybe `NULL` can be non-zero on some platforms, but zero should always be a null pointer. At least for the current standard.

Comment: @effeffe **For any integer type**. I don't think the quote from your answer addresses this. But the C FAQ does: **The internal (or run-time) representation of a null pointer, which may or may not be all-bits-0 and which may be different for different pointer types.**

Comment: So you're saying that conversion from integer to pointer could change the value? Well in that case you're right.

Comment: @effeffe All I am saying is that memsetting a pointer to 0 doesn't make it NULL on all platforms.

Comment: The discussion is reduced to that point: if that cast doesn't change the value, all-bits-0 is an integer zero and casting it to pointer type would result in null pointer with all-bits-0, so all-bits-0 would be a valid null pointer.

Comment: @effeffe What cast ? You should also bring it up with the more knowledgeable David Heffernan - he maintains the same thing in his answer.

Comment: @effeffe Where do you see any cast ? Are implying `memset` _needs_ casts ? You need to understand `x = 0` and `memset(&x, 0, sizeof 0)` are wildly different.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain my point well, I'll open a chat, I don't want to write too much comments.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21955/discussion-between-effeffe-and-cnicutar)

Answer (score 1):

The `memset` in your code will set all the bits to 0 which may or may not be what you want to do. In particular, it's not guaranteed that a pointer with all zero bits is the null pointer. Nor that a floating value with all zero bits is zero.

If you want your code to be completely portable then you should initialise each element.

```
my_struct_t *arr = malloc(N * sizeof arr[0]);
const my_struct_t default_my_struct = { 0 };
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    arr[i] = default_my_struct;
```

Or you could do the initialization with a C99 compound literal:

```
my_struct_t *arr = malloc(N * sizeof arr[0]);
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    arr[i] = (my_struct_t) { 0 };
```

In practise, you'll have to work hard to find a C implementation for which the code above will have a different result from your variant that uses `memset`.